# How to create a new instance of some model when instantiating some another model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to instantiate the Blog model when instantiating the User model and associate a new instance of the Blog model with a just created instance of the User model (and save both in database) by the OneToOneField.

I want always create a new instance of the Blog model when I creating a new instance of the User model and associate them by the OneToOneField.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # some logic to create a new instance of the Blog model 
    # and associating it with a just created instance of the User
    # by the OneToOneField 

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

How can I get it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use signals for that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/). So in your case it could look like this:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_blog(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Blog.objects.create(author=instance)
```

Comment: Whoah! Thank you, Krukas ^_^